# Multiple Choice user input and routing in Langchain Python

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain

I am building a chatbot for my website with Langchain and I want to lead the user through the conversation with different answer options that I want to predefine for each step.

So my chatbot will greet the user with a message like this:

> Hi there, how can I help you?
> Do you want to know more about:
>
> 1. my services
> 2. book appointment
> 3. personal information

So now, when the user types in "1" or "services", the chatbot should ask for the website of the user. This input should be then used to feed into an agent to do some research what the company is doing and show the results to the user for validation. I don't need a fully working example, I just need a push into the right direction how to approach this.

I tried it with `SequentialChain` and `MultiPromptChain` but I didn't had any luck to implement something close to the conversation flow I described above.

I guess I need multiple components for this. A memory buffer and a Router. I use the `ConversationSummaryMemoryBuffer` currently, but I don't know how to implement the flow I described with a Router and how the chatbot should understand in which step of the conversation we are? Is this done automatically by the `ConversationSummaryMemoryBuffer`?
Any helps is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this? i have a similar usecase

Comment: @mtshaikh No, I decided against Langchain.